# Build with gcc for systems with older gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Hi I am trying to build an executable on Ubuntu for RedHat 6.4 - and I am struggling due to the different gcc versions.

The RedHat 6.4 machine uses gcc 4.4.7. The Ubuntu machine uses gcc 4.6.3.

Here is what I have tried:

- Install g++-4.4 on the Ubuntu machine and compile with older version of gcc: failed because the code base uses features not yet available in g++-4.4
- Copy the Ubuntu libc.so.6 and libstdc++.so.6 over to the RedHat machine. The program sort of gets started, then segfaults.
- Link the executable on Ubuntu statically with -Wl,-Bstatic as link options. Failed on a third party library with "warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking".

So I am a bit stuck now... Any advice?

Comment: Build a newer version of gcc on RH 6.4?

Comment: +1. GCC 4.4.7 may not be able to compile your app, but it can definitely compile GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: Indeed. Pretty much your only options are to either modify the app to build with GCC 4.4.7, or to get GCC 4.6.3 running on your other machine. Welcome to the wonderful world of backporting.

Comment: Red Hat 6.4 is truly prehistoric, why are you using that at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments above, decided to dump RedHat (didn't have a subscription, so not easily upgradable) on the other machine and switch to Fedora, which has the latest gcc. Not a solution that scales, but what can you do.

Comment: Oh! Not Red Hat, but RHEL, a *big* difference right there. In that case, you can move to [CentOS](http://centos.org), binary compatible with RHEL (and today under the Red Hat umbrella). Fedora is nice, but has short life (a bit more than a year).